# getting Joomla category params

Tags: php, parameters, joomla

```
I have a color param in Joomla 3.0 component category.
```

and here is the div I want to give bg color.

I appreciate your answer.

```
category.xml


$app = JFactory::getApplication();


$template = $app->getTemplate(true);
  $params = $template->params;
  $eventcolor = $params->get("eventcolor");
```

I need to get my color param in my module and echo to my div background color. here is my code.

```
<div class="square" style="background-color:<?php echo $this->params->get('eventcolor'); ?> !important;"></div>
```

```html
<form>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic" label="Color settings">
            <field 
                    name = "eventcolor" 
                    type = "color"
                    default = "frontpage" 
                    validate = "color"
                    class="input-colorpicker"
                    value="#000" 
                    size="10"
                    label = "Kleur"
                    required = "true"
                    description = "Kies een event kleur"
                    

            </field>
        </fieldset>
          
    </fields>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already get

```
$eventcolor = $params->get("eventcolor");
```

Just echo $eventcolor

Answer (score 0):

In the main php file of a module, you have the variable `$params` available. But you try to use `$this->params` which is usually not available. To make your code work, please try this:

```
<div class="square" style="background-color:<?php echo $params->get('eventcolor'); ?> !important;"></div>
```

Not sure why you have that code part:

```
$template = $app->getTemplate(true);
$params = $template->params;
$eventcolor = $params->get("eventcolor");
```

It is not necessary if you use the main PHP file of a module.

Comment: I already used in the main PHP file (default.php) but What I want to retrieve from database is eventcolor and it's not working and giving error either.

Comment: Try print_r($params); or debug the template. What do $params contain? Do you see the eventcolor parameter in the modules configuration in the back end? Did you save the module at least one time?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure you are in the same component context, you need to use a code similar to this one in order to get the params list from the right component helper:

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_yourcomponent' );
```

Then, you can get and print the param in the way you were already doing:

```
<div class="square" style="background-color:<?php echo $params->get('eventcolor'); ?> !important;"></div>
```